# Android Application read write to physical memory

Tags: java, android, embedded

I'm new to Android and trying to look for advanced information about Android and Embedded systems.

I'm writing an APK application that needs to read/write to a physical memory of an embedded device.
It should achieve simple functionality as:

```
devmem [-switches] ADDRESS [w|b|h]      -- read memory and print
devmem [-switches] ADDRESS w|b|h VALUE  -- write VALUE into ADDRESS
```

and/or access to `/dev/mem` `mmap` `busybox`

What are the ways to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Android isn't really an embedded system, it's rather an OS for portable PCs.

Comment: for a reference my Androis OS runs under Xilinx ZCU102